# Count UL/OL items on external page

Tags: html, url, counter, embed, google-sites

I would like to count the UL / OL items on a specific page (static URL) and output this number as just text. So i can include this on another page and show how many list items (products) are currently being worked on.

I want to embed this on a Google Site, (using the embed feature) So i need a full `<html>` in/ output to make this all cross reference each other. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following script may help you to solve your problem.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://abcd.com/index.php',
            type:'GET',
            success: function(data){
                var ul_num = $(data).filter('ul').find("li").length;
                var ol_num = $(data).filter('ol').find("li").length;
                $('#result').append('UL Count: ' + ul_num + '</br/> OL Count: '+ol_num);
            }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="result"></div>
```